# error in rendering a form partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I am trying to render a page on a click event in Rails app.

In my page I am rendering the partial like `<%= render "form" %>`

My form partial is under `contacts/_form.html.erb`.

In my `_form.html.erb` I have form fields.

But I am not getting the form rendered.

This is the error I am getting

> Missing partial pages/form with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"

below is my `_form.html.erb`

```
  <%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
    <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Email"%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :phone %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :phone, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Phone Number"%>
     </div>
     </div> 
     </div>

   <div class = "col-md-8">
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :description %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :description,  :class=>"form-control", :size=>"20x5", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Message"%>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Submit", :class=> "button1"%>
  </div>  
 <% end %>
```

What am I Doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling your partial from an `erb` file which which is in scope of `pages_controller`, thats why it's trying to find your `_form` partial under `views/pages` directory.

You need to give proper path for `_form` as:

```
<%= render "contacts/form" %>
```

**EDIT:**

As now you are facing `model_name' for NilClass:Class` error. It means, `@contact` in first line of your `_form` is `nil`. You have not initialized `@contact`. Try following:

```
<%#= Preferably, you should initialize '@contact = Contact.new' in your action and form should be unchanged %>
<%= form_for(Contact.new) do |f| %>
```

Comment: With this I am getting ` undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
`

Comment: @Suraj Updated answer. If still you face issue, post your corresponding action

Answer (score 0):

> Missing partial pages/form with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder,
>   :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
>   "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"

Since your form is under ***contacts*** folder and you are trying to render it in ***pages***, you need add the location of the partial too.

```
<%= render "contacts/form" %>
```

Comment: With this I am getting ` undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
`